# How to get subcollection from firestore using react-redux-firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

I am not able to get the sub-collection from my Firestore data.

I followed the documentation [here](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/api/firestoreConnect.html). And also looked at many other similar question on this.

I can't seem to get the array of data that i want to get.

## My code:

```
import "../../styles/projects/ProjectDashboard.css";
import ProjectList from "./ProjectList";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { firestoreConnect } from "react-redux-firebase";
import { compose } from "redux";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export class ProjectDashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    const { projects, auth } = this.props;
    if (!auth.uid) return <Redirect to="/sigin" />;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h2>Projects</h2>
        <ProjectList projects={projects} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state);
  return {
    projects: state.firestore.ordered.projects,
    auth: state.firebase.auth
  };
};

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  firestoreConnect(props => {
    return [
      {
        collection: "users",
        doc: props.auth.uid,
        subcollection: [{ collection: "projects" }]
      }
    ];
  })
)(ProjectDashboard);
```

this is what i am getting now from my console :

```
firestore:
|-composite: undefined
|-data: {users: {…}}
|-errors: {byQuery: {…}, allIds: Array(0)}
|-listeners: {byId: {…}, allIds: Array(1)}
|-ordered:
|--users: Array(1)
|---0: {id: "o06VEyRbGDcURTmKal3gDEDZQO73", firstName: "testing", lastName: "you", userId: "o06VEyRbGDcURTmKal3gDEDZQO73"}
|---length: 1
|---__proto__: Array(0)
|--__proto__: Object
|-queries: {}
|-status: {requesting: {…}, requested: {…}, timestamps: {…}}
|-__proto__: Object
```

I was thinking that my code will change this part:

```
|-ordered:
|--users: Array(1)
|---0: {id: "o06VEyRbGDcURTmKal3gDEDZQO73", firstName: "testing", lastName: "you", userId: "o06VEyRbGDcURTmKal3gDEDZQO73"}
```

to something like this:

```
|-ordered:
|--projects: Array(3)
|---0: {id: "o06VEyRbGDcURTmKal3gDEDZQO73", firstName: "testing", lastName: "you", userId: "o06VEyRbGDcURTmKal3gDEDZQO73"}
|---1: {id: "o06VEyRbGDcURTmKal3gDEDZQO73", firstName: "testing", lastName: "you", userId: "o06VEyRbGDcURTmKal3gDEDZQO73"}
|---2: {id: "o06VEyRbGDcURTmKal3gDEDZQO73", firstName: "testing", lastName: "you", userId: "o06VEyRbGDcURTmKal3gDEDZQO73"}
```

so i can get the array through the key. But now i am at a lost on how to change it into my sub-collection key.

Comment: Do refer to redux-firestore from the same author. Read the sub collections section of this link:
https://github.com/prescottprue/redux-firestore make sure to use storeAs for subcollections.

Answer (score 1):

I realised that it should be "subcollections" and not "subcollection"